# Vga driver for Ubuntu-Server 11.10

Tags: server, drivers, resolution, vga

Dear All,

I am using Ubuntu Server 11.10 which is running on Intel server board S1200BT family G20500-003,..

But the resolution of the LCD monitor is very low (800x600),i want to change the monitor resolution, i really don't know what to do ?.

Please help me out ,...

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and type as `xrandr` then it will display whats the minimum , maximum ,current resolution and with some indexes .

from there a list of resolution display will be shown to you ,so choose whats your desired resolution of the display .

for first resolution give as `xrandr -s 0` and for 2nd resolution give as `xrandr -s 1` . like that you can choose what exact resolution you want .

hope that helps . 
all the best.

Comment: output:Screen 0: minimum 128 x 128, current 800 x 600, maximum 800 x 800
LVDS connected 800x600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   800x600        59.9*

Comment: when i try to add new resolution the output is :          xrandr --newmode "800x800_60.00"   51.75  800 840 920 1040  800 803 813 831 -hsync +vsync                                                           xrandr --addmode LVDS "800x800_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  21